# How do I track data flowing through a codebase? Like finding all references to an object after it has been passed through deep function calls?

Tags: intellij-idea, reference, language-server-protocol, codebase

When I'm going over a codebase, I wanna see how a piece of data flows throughout that codebase. For example, when I have an object, I wanna know how the object's reference gets passed around to various functions/methods/etc. I don't just mean "Find references/usages" that LSPs and IDEs provide.

Here's an example in python:

```py
data = {
    'foo': 123
}

def do_1(param1):
    print(param1['foo'])
    do_2(param1)

def do_2(param2):
    print(param2['foo'])

do_1(data)
```

Here I have the object `data`. I want to know all the places where this object is referenced, so that I can tell which places will be relevant when I have do something to this object (for example, change its structure). When I do "find references" using the python LSP (pyright), it finds only the last line of the code. However, I would like to also find the usages of param1 and param2 because they're also referencing the same object.

I wrote the same code in Java and tried this using intellij's "Find usages" feature, but I got the same results as with python's LSP.

Currently my workflow is:

1. Find all references of variable
2. For each reference where variable is used as function argument, go to function definition
3. Repeat 1.

I would like the editor/IDE to do this grunt work for me.